# Printing of a web page doesn’t look like what is expected from the browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, printing, microsoft-edge

I would like to print web page. But looks like something is trying to hide right side of page from printing.

Besides that I can't find page orientation selection in order to set page landscape. This happens in both browsers Chrome and Edge. How to avoid these pitfalls and print page?

In browser:

[image]

In print menu:

[image]

**UPDATE**: I was trying to print to Microsoft Print to PDF, but got the same problems.

Comment: This happens in both browsers Chrome and Edge.    .........   Have you tried updating the printer driver?  Can you get someone with a different printer to try the page?

Comment: This might be an error in the webpage itself. Could we have a link to examine?

Comment: I don’t see what is missing here. The browser view and print menu view seem to be the same to me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the destination from Microsoft Print to PDF to Save as PDF? On my device doing that enables the option to change the page orientation.

If you click "More settings" you get an option to change the margin and scale which might help reduce that white border over the page.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to set your web browser webpage area the same size of the target area size to be printed, then take a screeshot. On your favorite word processor or whatevever app that give you good control of the printed page settings, create a printable *file* (document, presentation, etc.), paste the screenshot, save the file and print it from that application.

*Your mileage might vary*

Depending on web page, your skills to handle your web browser (i.e. resize the window),
customize the DOM (i.e. change the web page background color), to take the screenshoot, etc., will be the quality of the image.

Depending on options of application that you have, the one that you choose and the printer that you have there will be the options that you will have to control the printing process / quality.

---

The above because some webpages might have stylesheets that are a mess regarding making the webpage printing friendly, just because the developer just didn't care about making the webpage printing friendly, they focused on other things.

---

Related

- [How to get WYSIWYP (print what you see) in a web browser?](https://superuser.com/q/846082/152004)